# What's wrong with this addition method?

Tags: c++, class, methods, console-application

So this is the declaration of the method in the public inheritance of the Vector class:

```
Vector Addition(Vector a, Vector b);
```

And here is the implementation outside of class:

```
Vector Vector::Addition(Vector a, Vector b)
{
    Vector temp = *this;
    temp.x=a.x+b.x;
    temp.y=a.y+b.y;
    return temp;
}
```

And when I do this in main function:

```
Vector c(0,0),a(0,0),b(0,0);
c=Addition(a,b);
```

I get the error: Identifier "Addition" is undefined. Please help!

Comment: If you want to use `Addition` in that way it has to be a free function, not a method.

Comment: Except then `*this` won't work. I'm not sure what that offers over `return {a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y};`, though, with a proper constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `Addition` function is a member of `Vector`, you have to call it as such:

```
c = Vector::Addition(a, b);
```

or

```
c = a.Addition(b);
```

Note that the first one requires the `Addition` function to be *static*, meaning that it doesn't operate on a concrete instance (`this` in the function body):

```
static Vector Addition(Vector a, Vector b);
```

But then you can't access a `this` pointer, so you have to default-construct `temp` instead of taking a copy (which is, by the way, unused since you overwrite `x` and `y` anyway).

The second one uses the left hand side operand as the `this` pointer within your implementation (no `a` in the signature).

```
Vector Addition(Vector b)
{
    Vector temp = *this;
    temp.x += b.x;
    temp.y += b.y;
    return temp;
}
```

Note that you can also *overload operators* in C++. For this, define a non-static member function called `operator+` which takes a second instance (the first instance is the `this` pointer within the function which will be the left hand side operand):

```
Vector operator+(const Vector &other) const;
```

The implementation (one possibility):

```
Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector &other)
{
    Vector temp = *this;
    temp.x += other.x;
    temp.y += other.y;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Just one more question. Why do you have to write const in brackets of overloaded operator +? Is it a mistake if you just write
Vector operator+(Vector &other);

Comment: @A6Tech, You're not modifying it, so why make it non-const? It just limits what you can pass in, whether const objects or temporaries. Note that another popular method is to use a free function, take the left side by value, and call `operator+=` on it.

Comment: @chris I guess you explained the const in the brackets. But what about the one after them?

Comment: @A6Tech, That means it can't modify the calling object (save `mutable` members), so it can be called with `<const object> + <other object>`.

Answer (score 4):

```
c=Addition(a,b);
```

Tells the compiler to call a function freestanding function. You have provided a member function not a freestanding function so the compiler cannot find any and it complains.

You need to provide a freestanding function.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `Addition` inside `Vector`. The correct way would be to ...

(1) Have Addition as a global function. This would involve you taking the definition of Addition out of the Vector class. Thus it would look like

```
Vector Addition(/*parameters*/) { /* implementation */ }
```

(2) Make Addition static with the `static` keyword, and call it with the code `c = Vector::Addition(a, b)`.

The code would look like

```
 class Vector{
 static Vector Addition(/* arguments */);
}

Vector Vector::Addition(/*arguments*/) {/*implementation*/}
```